# updating related tables in cake

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-update

I have this:

```
$this->request->data['Person']['person_id'] = $this->Session->read('insertedPersonID');
$savedPerson = $this->Person->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate'=>'first'));
```

which updates the selected person row fine however its related tables like PersonColor and PersonParts are not updating, instead inserting new rows.

I thought cake automatically updates the related tables as well as long as the id of the main table which is the foreign key for the other two tables are provided since doing this:

```
$savedPerson = $this->Person->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate'=>'first'));
```

inserts to the Person table and the other two related two tables fine.

How do I make it update the other two tables as well?

**Edit:**
For the model relations:

Person Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
  'PersonParts' => array(
    'className' => 'Part',
    'foreignKey' => 'part_person_id'
   ),
  'PersonColors' => array(
    'className' => 'Color',
    'foreignKey' => 'color_person_id'
   )
);
```

Part Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
  'PartPerson' => array(
    'className' => 'Person',
    'foreignKey' => 'part_person_id'
   )
);
```

Color Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
 'ColorPerson' => array(
    'className' => 'Person',
    'foreignKey' => 'color_person_id',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
   )
);
```

**edit 2**

var_dump of $this->request->data

```
array(3){
    ["Person"]=>array(4){
        ["person_user_id"]=>string(1)"3"
        ["person_name"]=>string(9)"Britney"
        ["person_category_id"]=>string(2)"16"
        ["visibility"]=>string(1)"1"
        ["person_id"]=>string(1)"71"
    }
    ["PersonParts"]=>array(1){
        [0]=>array(3){
            ["part_name"]=>string(4)"hands"
            ["quantity"]=>string(1)"2"
            ["part_part_type_id"]=>string(1)"1"
        }
    }
    ["PersonColors"]=>array(2){
        [0]=>array(4){
            ["color_name"]=>string(3)"blue"
            ["test_field1"]=>string(1)"8"
            ["test_field2"]=>string(1)"9"
            ["position"]=>int(1)
        }
        [1]=>array(2){
            ["color_name"]=>string(5)"red"
            ["position"]=>int(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This var_dump is only showing ["person_id"]=>string(1)"71" under Person array as the added field to make cake do an update, not insert... person_id is not showing under the PersonParts and PersonColors here since it's not working that way. What should I pass or How should I do an update on the other 2 related tables?

Comment: can you paste the code related to relations from the Person, Personcolor and PersonParts models?

Comment: @cornelb Okay, I posted the Model relations on the question after "Edit"

Comment: Can you post a var_dump of $this->request->data before it's saved?

Comment: @BenHitchcock Okay, it's under "edit 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Cake do an update on the related tables, you do need to pass in the id of the related record, otherwise Cake won't know which record to update.

You can make this a hidden field in your form, which is how I do things.

The var dump for PersonParts should look like this (note the extra 'part_id' field):

```
["PersonParts"]=>array(1){
    [0]=>array(3){
        ["part_id"]=>string(1)"7"
        ["part_name"]=>string(4)"hands"
        ["quantity"]=>string(1)"2"
        ["part_part_type_id"]=>string(1)"1"
    }
}
```

If you don't pass the id, then (from memory) Cake will delete the existing related records, and add new ones.

Comment: I added this $this->request->data['PersonColors'][$key]['color_id'] = 92; and it shows under the PersonColors's first array fine but it's still notupdating that row

Comment: Have you set the primaryKey properly in the Color model?

Comment: Yes, I have. Like this : public $primaryKey = 'color_id';

Comment: And this 92 I'm using for color_id is an already saved row data in the database to check if its value is going to be changed but it's not updating. :(

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm doing this under a different controller since Color and Part are of different models.

Comment: No, it's not that.  I update different models like you're trying to do all the time, and it works with no problems.  I'd try stepping through the code with xdebug to see what's really going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I'll just accept your answer as a way of thanking you. Your answer is the same as what I was already doing. It seems the error was with the part_id Model validation which was set to 'blank'.

Comment: Thanks Sandara, I'm glad you got it figured out in the end.