# cakephp: update hasmany related tables

Tags: php, cakephp, has-many, insert-update

For example, if we have:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [title] => On Gwoo the Kungwoo
                    [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [title] => More on Gwoo
                    [body] => But what of the 'Nut?
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
                )
        )
)
```

from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

How should we do an update on the Comment table from the User controller given that all these data is submitted using one form?

This is somehow the same as my question here: [updating related tables in cake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079057/updating-related-tables-in-cake/21104391?noredirect=1#comment31753724_21104391) which I unfortunately got no correct answer. Can someone enlighten me on how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $this->User->saveAssociated($yourArray);

it will save all the data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use saveAll as described in Cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array

```
$this->User->saveAll($data)
```